# rails - css randomly breaking on navigation bar

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, heroku, assets

The website is up and running:

www.glimp.co.nz

Randomly the css stops working ( not sure of the trigger ) and elements on the nav bar ( see pictures ) revert back to the default bootstrap css.

CSS broken on Nav:
[image]

Footer not sticking at bottom:
[image]

-nav.html.erb

```
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="/">
        <img alt="Brand" src="/assets/compareswitchsave.png" height="70" width="150" >
      </a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      </ul>

      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li id="nav-broadband-link"><a id="nav-broadband-link-GA" href="/broadband/search">BROADBAND</a></li>
        <li><a href="/#aboutus">ABOUT US</a></li>
        <li><a href="#new-index-footer" id="contact-us-nav-link" onclick="footerContactUsJiggle()">CONTACT US</a></li>

      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

nav.scss

```
.navigation>img {
  width: 170px;
  height: 70px;
  margin-left: 35px;
}

.navigation>a {
  float: right;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
  display: inline;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 30px 40px 0px 0px;
  color: #AB47BC;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 15px;
}

.navigation>a:hover {
  color: #ccc;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.navbar-brand {
  margin-left: 5% !important;
}


.navbar-brand>img {
  margin-left: 5% !important;
}
```

This happens intermittently but mostly on mobile devices, desktop works fine whilst mobile css goes hay wire. However sometimes desktop css breaks whilst mobile is fine.

Sometimes when the css breaks it also stops any javascript from working, however this is not always the case.

In order to correct this `enter code here`I have to delete the sprockets file and re compile the assets and then push back up to heroku to fix the issue. I have to repeat this process every time the css breaks.

I am not sure if it is a bootstrap issue, or the way rails compiles css or something to do with the partials we are using, but any help would be awesome!

application.html.erb

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>glimp - Compare Broadband Spark Vodafone Slingshot Orcon Flip Bigpipe Compass Unlimited</title>

    <!-- <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1"> -->
    <%= stylesheet_link_tag    'application', media: 'all' %>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">

    <%= javascript_include_tag 'application' %>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-easing/1.3/jquery.easing.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      (function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
      (i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
      m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
      })(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

      ga('create', 'UA-70480672-1', 'auto');
      ga('send', 'pageview');
    </script>
    <!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <script>
    !function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
    n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
    n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
    t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
    document,'script','//connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');

    fbq('init', '1660762074163778');
    fbq('track', "PageView");</script>
    <noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
    src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=1660762074163778&ev=PageView&noscript=1"
    /></noscript>
    <!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
    <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  </head>
  <body>
    <script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
          appId      : '995092153863062',
          xfbml      : true,
          version    : 'v2.5'
        });
      };

      (function(d, s, id){
         var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
         if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
         js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
         js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
         fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
       }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
    </script>

    <!-- Google Tag Manager -->



      <noscript>
        <iframe src="//www.googletagmanager.com/ns.html?id=GTM-TS7QXF" height="0" width="0" style="display:none;visibility:hidden"></iframe>
      </noscript>
      <script>
      (function(w,d,s,l,i){w[l]=w[l]||[];w[l].push({'gtm.start':
      new Date().getTime(),event:'gtm.js'});var f=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0],
      j=d.createElement(s),dl=l!='dataLayer'?'&l='+l:'';j.async=true;j.src=
      '//www.googletagmanager.com/gtm.js?id='+i+dl;f.parentNode.insertBefore(j,f);
      })(window,document,'script','dataLayer','GTM-TS7QXF');
      </script>
    <!-- End Google Tag Manager -->
    <%= render 'navigation/nav'%>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <%= yield %>
    </div>
    <%= render 'social_icons/social_icons'%>
    <div class="push"></div>
    <%= render 'footer/foot'%>
  </body>

</html>
```

footer.scss

```
/*********************
  MAIN FOOTER STYLING
*********************/

  .new-index-footer {
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 80px;
  }

  .footer-links>a {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .footer-links>a:visited {
    color: lightgrey;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  a:hover {
    color: black;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .footer-links {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 30px;
  }



  #new-index-footer>img{
    float: left;
    margin-top: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
  }

  .a-tag-container {
    text-align: right;
    height: 100%;
  }


@media only screen and (min-width: 320px) and (max-width: 768px){


  .footer-links {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 30px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    margin-right: 5px;
  }

  #new-index-footer>img{
      display: none;
  }

   #contact-us-footer-link {
    margin-right: 0;
  }

  .a-tag-container {
    text-align: center;
    height: 100%;
  }

  .other-info-footer-links{
    margin-right: 10px;
  }

}


/**************************
   OTHER FOOTER STYLING
**************************/



  .other-info-footer{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 30px;
  }

  .other-info-footer-links {
    display: inline-block;
    text-align: center;
    margin-right: 30px;
    margin-left: 30px;
  }

  .other-info-footer-links>a {
    font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
    color: grey;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }

  .other-info-footer-links>a:visited {
    color: lightgrey;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: bold;
  }
```

Comment: You need to provide more information about your problem here other than the `CSS randomly stops working`. Also your screenshots are identical, I am not sure where the difference is. Since you are using bootstrap, you can try putting your source code on [Bootply][1] so that we can further test and take a look at your issue.


  [1]: http://bootply.com/ "Bootply"